# Where should I put SpBackupDatabases.sql my user database or master database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found some backup and restore stored procedures here, my question is where I should I put those scripts? In my user database or master database?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jenss/archive/2011/09/08/bulk-backup-and-restore-at-the-tip-of-your-finger.aspx

Comment: Obviously in user DB. Why do you want to put that in Master?

Comment: It looks like a stored procedure I want to use for multiple databases, so I am not sure it make sense to put in a specific database.

Comment: User specific DB objects shouldn't be present in Master DB. Moreover, if you put it in DB1 why can't you use it in DB2 ... just qualify the name accordingly like `DB1.dbo.mysp`

Comment: That make sense, do you want to make it answer, and I can accept it as answer.

Comment: Was not thinking to put it as answer but anyways have put it as answer per your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you want to place it in user DB. Why do you want to put that in Master?
User specific DB objects shouldn't be present in `Master` DB. Moreover, if you put it in DB1 why can't you use it in DB2 ... just qualify the name accordingly like `DB1.dbo.mysp` (using 3 part naming scheme).

Comment: The obvious reason for not putting it in just any user DB is because the user DB might go away. If it's a stored proc that's going to work against all DBs on the instance, putting it in an application database  or vendor database means you lose your stored proc when the app or vendor goes away. I like to create a user DB just for maintenance on my instances to keep my instance maintenance separate from my applications and system databases.

Comment: @BaconBits, That's true but simply a user DB will not go away (just like that) ... not even in DEV DB server. moreover, creating a separate DB altogether is a good idea but at the end of the day .. that's too a user DB.

Answer (score 2):

It will function if you use `master`, but using any of the system databases is usually considered poor practice.

If you need to have a maintenance stored procedure for multiple databases on an instance, I personally prefer to create a separate user database just for that.  We have index optimization stored procedures used in maintenance plans that are stored in a separate `maint` database, for example.  Just create a new DB, set the recovery model to Simple to keep logs from growing endlessly (unless you're planning on backing up the transaction logs for the `maint` database, too), add your stored procedures, log tables, etc. and away you go.